# How to get a vim-tab-like short path in bash script?

Tags: bash

I'd like to create a `bash` prompt that includes a shortened path to the current working directory, so

```
~/folder/directory/foo
```

would become

```
~/f/d/foo
```

I got this idea from a custom `bash` prompt described here (http://engineerwithoutacause.com/show-current-virtualenv-on-bash-prompt.html) which includes code that's supposed to do exactly that (according to the comment) but doesn't.  I don't know anything about `bash` scripting, but I bet this would be an easy one to answer.

What line or lines of code in a bash script will let me generate that shortened version of the working directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed` is easiest because of regex backreference support, but for fun and profit a pure `bash` solution:

```
path="$(while read -rd/; do echo -n ${REPLY::1}/; done <<< "$PWD"; echo "${PWD##*/}")"
```

The value of `$PWD` is fed into the `while` loop via the herestring syntax `<<<`, then split on slashes by `read -rd/`. Conveniently, the last component is ignored because it doesn't end in a slash, so `read` exits with a nonzero status and terminates the loop.

Inside the loop, `${REPLY::1}` takes only the first character of the path component, and `echo -n` prints it without a newline.

Finally, we print the last pathname component in full using `${PWD##*/}`, which strips the longest prefix that matches `*/`.

Comment: This does the trick.  However, how do I take the above, and feed it into a variable?  As in the link I referenced, I want to create a variable called `path` to hold this output, then insert into my bash prompt with other stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You can put your `$PWD` variable (a string with your current directory) to being changed by a `sed` command, as in:

`echo $PWD | sed 's:/\(.\)[^/]*/:/\1/:g'`

Basically, this sed is finding everything (`g`) that is between two `/` (and that's why I'm using `:` as a delimiter), and replacing it to just the first char (the `.` enclosed by `\(` and `\)`, referenced as `\1` later), surrounded by `/`s again.

If you set this to your `PS1` variable, you can change your bash prompt as request.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This gets me part way but isn't quite working.  If my $PWD is /home/joe/Dropbox/foo/bar/folder, I would expect /h/j/D/f/b/folder, but instead I'm getting just /h/folder.

Comment: OK, figured it out.  This works for the `sed` command: `sed "s:\(.\)[^/]*/:\1/:g"`.  Your code used a greedy regex that took the whole path as "something between two `/`".  Mine now matches any set of characters that aren't slashes, plus a single slash, so it won't grab the whole path.

Answer (score 1):

Combining the information at the link I referenced in the question, with Fernando's answer and some research of my own into regex, This is the code that provides the path I want:

```
pwd | sed -e "s:$HOME:~:" -e "s:\(.\)[^/]*/:\1/:g"
```

The first `sed` pattern replaces my home directory `/home/joe` with a `~` and the second one replaces every multi-character directory name with its first character.

If anyone's interested, the complete code for my bashprompt is here: https://gist.github.com/joeclark-phd/d6be2dca717788e6a872.  The part you helped me with is in line 39.